# Run Talend job on a Unix-like machine

Tags: java, linux, noclassdeffounderror, talend

I try to run simple job generated from Talend Open Studio v5.4.0. 
It invokes a web service and save responce into an XML file. On my development (Windows 7) machine everything works fine.

On RHEL machine, with this version of Java:

```
[root@localhost checkws]# java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

when I try to run my job I get:

```
[root@localhost checkws]# sh checkws_run.sh
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: routines/system/api/TalendJob
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: routines.system.api.TalendJob
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 13 more
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: To solve this issue I exported job both for Windows and Linux platform

Comment: You can answer your own questions if it really solves the problem :)

Comment: @MaxKvt Balazs is right: post your solution as an answer and accept it, please. In this way people will see immediately that the question is solved and doesn't need a solution anymore. ;)

Comment: @MaxKvt Well, I posted it myself, so everyone can clearly see the solution

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue (like the OP did) I exported the job both for Windows and Linux platforms. Seems to be a bug in Talend exportation.

Comment: For me, TOS 3.2.2.r33000) I exported for Unix only and checked "Export Dependencies"

Comment: @Joand please write your solution as an answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

On TOS 3.2.2.r33000 I exported for Unix only and checked "Export Dependencies"

Answer (score 0):

Talend generate a zip package which work fine in Windows (using a bat file) and Linux (using a sh file). The sh have all lib jars in classpath.

If you want to change the lib path, and add dynamically all jars in your lib path, this is a way to do that.

```
#!/bin/sh
cd `dirname $0`

path_lib=/path/to/your/lib/directory

# include all jars in lib directory to classpath
for jar_file in `find $path_lib -name "*.jar"`
do
classpath="${jar_file}:${classpath}"
done

# x_y is the version of your job, x_y = 0_1 for the first version of a talend job.
java -Xms256M -Xmx1024M -cp ${classpath} projectname.jobname_x_y.jobname --context=Default "$@"
```